# My texture mapping keeps coming out wrong

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I created a texture for ductwork for a project that I am working on and I wanted to export it into glTF. I know that in order to do so I need to bake the textures, and that while baking textures to turn the metallic value to 0. I baked the color, roughness, metallic, and normal maps and created a new material that would be glTF compliant. When I imported all of the maps and attached them, the material came out completely different.

The shader nodes:
[image]

What the texture is supposed to look like:
[image]

New material nodes:
[image]

What it comes out looking like:
[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Things I've tried:
Plugging the normal map into the displacement output
Plugging the image texture itself into the displacement.
Wrapping UVs in different ways
Baking textures as they are applied on a plane

Comment: Pack your images and attach the .blend.

Comment: Apart from the bump looking less strong I mostly see one problem: repeating patterns. The problem here is, you bake the normal map (and the other textures) onto UV maps. They are limited in size and will be repeated. Your procedural _Wave Texture_ with _Generated_ coordinates is not repeating over the size of the object. Apart from that, you have plugged the _Bump_ node into the _Displacement_ - but this only intensifies the bump (in _Material Preview_), unless the material is set to show displacement (but even then it will not be displaced by the texture, just uniformly in normal direction).

Answer (score 1):

With the response from Gordon Brinkmann, I applied the array modifier I had set to the ducting, then I unwrapped each ducting separately and created texture maps for each ducting, this stopped the repeating patterns and made the overall ducting look more realistic.